# Having trouble understanding the solution for the 10x10 board problem

Tags: combinatorics

The [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481444/10-by-10-board-problem) was posted by [Matheo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/92596/matheo):

> We place the numbers 1,2,...,100 on the 100 squares of a 10 by 10
>   board. We then take the third greatest number from each row and create
>   their sum S. Prove that at least one row has a sum of numbers that is
>   less than S.

and was answer by [Rebecca](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/91818/rebecca).

I understood half of it. But at this part it starts to look confusing:

> The sum of the entries of $M_i$ must be at most $$8(i+1)
>  \mathbf{x_{i7}}-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{8(i+1)-1} k\right).$$ 
>   (The maximum is achieved when the numbers in $M_i$ are the $8(i+1)$ largest integers not exceeding $\mathbf{x_{i7}}$.)

I'm not a really bright person.. So I would like to know why in order to compute the biggest possible value for $M_i$, we need to first

> $$8(i+1)
>  \mathbf{x_{i7}}$$

What is the reason behind multiplying $8(i+1)$, which is $\mathbf{x_{i7}}$'s smallest possible value, with $\mathbf{x_{i7}}$?

And how is the maximum achieved when the numbers in $M_i$ are the $8(i+1)$ largest integers not exceeding $\mathbf{x_{i7}}$?

What does it mean by being "the $8(i+1)$ largest integers but smaller than $\mathbf{x_{i7}}$"?

Comment: The reason for multiplying $\mathbf{x_{i7}}$ with $8(i+1)$ is that the matrix $M_i$ contains $8(i+1)$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true for any integer matrix $M=(m_{ij})_{m \times n}$ without repeated numbers.  The sum of the entries of $M$ is at most $$nm\max(M)-\sum_{k=1}^{nm-1} k.$$  In the particular matrix in the earlier question, it was an $8 \times (i+1)$ matrix with maximum $\mathbf{x}_{i7}$.

---

Let's use this as a running example: $$M=\begin{array}{|ccccc|} \hline 12 & 30 & 36 & 7 & 34 \\ 24 & 38 & 25 & 6 & 28 \\ 20 & 32 & -5 & 37 & 0 \\ \hline \end{array}.$$

- Let $X=(x_{ij})_{m \times n}$ be the matrix defined by $x_{ij}=\max(M)$.

  So, in our example $\max(M)=38$ and so $$X=\begin{array}{|ccccc|} \hline 38 & 38 & 38 & 38 & 38 \\ 38 & 38 & 38 & 38 & 38 \\ 38 & 38 & 38 & 38 & 38 \\ \hline \end{array}.$$
- Let $D=(d_{ij})_{m \times n}$ be defined by $D=X-M$.

  So, in our example  $$D=\begin{array}{|ccccc|} \hline 26 & 8 & 2 & 31 & 4 \\ 14 & 0 & 13 & 32 & 10 \\ 18 & 6 & 43 & 1 & 38 \\ \hline \end{array}.$$

We have defined $X$ and $D$ such that $M=X-D$.  So the sum of entries in $M$ is the sum of entries in $X$ minus the sum of entries in $D$.

By definition, the sum of entries in $X$ is $nm\max(M)$.

The matrix $D$ contains $0$ and $nm-1$ distinct positive integers.  The smallest possible sum of $nm-1$ distinct positive integers is $\sum_{k=1}^{nm-1} k$ (which are the $nm-1$ smallest positive integers).  Hence the sum of entries in $M$ is at most $$nm\max(M)-\sum_{k=1}^{nm-1} k.$$  (We could make this last step formal by creating a sorted list from the entries of $D$ and showing each element is no smaller than the corresponding element in the sequence $(0,1,\ldots,nm-1)$.)

Comment: I get it now! Thank you!